# Merge duplicate answers

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I see answers to questions that are exact duplicates. Perhaps we should have a feature where you can merge duplicate answers together. (Two users get credit for one answer)

I am aware that this is almost what an upvote would do for an answer, in the sense that if someone agrees with the answer given an upvote will help affirm the validity of the answer.

This will keep answers clean, and both users who answer can benefit reputation wise.

**Note:** There would have to be a limit, so that users can't post a duplicate answer just to get in on the reputation benefit.

Comment: Or just flag to delete the newer one...

Comment: Right, but that undercuts user of the other valid answer. This contributes to the Fastest gun in the west problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: If they are exact duplicates, what benefit would merging them have? Merging questions at least combines two sets of answers.

Comment: The benefit is for the users posting the answers. And it keeps the list of answers clean on the question

Comment: Until it gets a downvote and we get some Meta whine "this was not exactly my answer, mine was a bit better, but now I do get the other users's downvotes". If they are exactly, word for word, 100% the same, just delete the later one. If they are different formulations of the same approach, just let them exist.

Comment: good point, i see now it is more trouble than it is worth

Answer (score 1):

Well we could just take the one that was addressed first...

If you do have enough reputation or with someone that has enough rep. points, should remove duplicates...

OR there should be a Duplicate Detection and Removal Function!!

**Better to Prevent and Cure!**

Comment: "Better to Prevent and Cure!" Er, shouldn't that be one or the other?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yeah, I think it's supposed to be "better to prevent *than* cure"?  But I'm not a doctor.  ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard If you were a doctor, you'd prefer curing over people preventing I'd say. Then again, that might just be me and the world should perhaps be glad I'm not a doctor...

Comment: @Bart I have read an article a couple of years ago that actually prevention costs more and gives more profit to physicians and pharmaceutical companies than curing for most diseases. (Since curing mostly consists of a week or so in bed and maybe $20 worth of medicine once every five [or whatever] years; most people don't get the disease even without prevention.)